# Adding different value to different row in a dataframe

Tags: r

To add the value `1.45` from rows 1 to 10 and value `2.55` for rows 10 onward under a new column, I able to do so with the following R code

```
 df$colone <- c(rep(1.45, 10), rep(NA, nrow(df) - 10))

 df$coltwo <- c(rep(NA, 10), rep(2.55, nrow(df) - 10))
```

However, I want to add `1.45` for the first N row, `2.55` the next N row, "4.55" the next N row all under one single column.

How do I go about doing in R?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rep` with `each` option.  Assuming that the number of rows is 30 and `N = 10`

```
df$col1 <- rep(c(1.45, 2.55, 4.55), each = N)
```

If the number of rows are not a multiple of 'N', say greater than 30 we can pad the additional elements with `NA`

```
df$col1 <- `length<-`(rep(c(1.45, 2.55, 4.55), each = N), nrow(df))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun There are 3744 rows in the data. First 469 rows are for 1.45, from 469 to 937 row is 2.55 and so on

Comment: @Yap You can change `N <- 469` i.e. `"length<-"(rep(c(1.45, 2.55, 4.55), N), 3744)`